# Read binary data from stdin on Win32, and write it to file

Tags: windows, console, pipe

What is the Windows (Win32) command-line equivalent of the Unix pipeline:

```
myprog myarg | cat >out.dat
```

Please note that I want to have a pipe, to test that myprog can write successfully to a pipe, so please don't simplify it to this:

```
myprog myarg >out.dat
```

I'd guess something like

```
myprog myarg | copy /b con out.dat
```

would work, but I don't have a Windows machine to check.

Please note that the generated data is binary, it contains all possible bytes values 0 .. 255, and all of them must be preserved intact, without any transformation.

Comment: I don't think there's technically any difference between writing redirected output to a pipe vs. a file.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: Nevertheless, I'd like to write to pipe, just to be 100% sure that it works properly.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to tell you - if it writes to the file 100% properly, it will write to the pipe 100% properly as well. There's no way one could work but the other not, since Windows itself takes care of the details. Your program doesn't see any difference.

Comment: I understand that you think it works that way, but I'd also like to try it myself, because something strange is going on with pipes, and I'd like to debug it.

Comment: @Mark: there could be differences, depending on what the code does.  For example, attempts to reposition the handle will work on a file but fail (or, I suspect, be silently ignored) on a pipe.  There are probably more subtle cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing built into Windows equivalent to the way you're using `cat` in the example given.  The command you suggest (`copy /b con`) certainly won't work, because `con` is the console device, not the standard input.

You could try the [GNU utilities for Win32](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/), which includes a port of `cat`.  Otherwise you may need to write your own code, which would of course be simple enough.

Comment: Addendum: `findstr .` would work in many scenarios.  You would need to be aware that it suppresses blank lines, and doesn't cope well with Unicode.

Answer (score 9):

Since Windows doesn't come with such a program, here's a quick one in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    char buffer[16384];
    int count;
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_BINARY);
    while ((count = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), stdin)) != 0)
        fwrite(buffer, 1, count, stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

You can easily modify it to write to a file of your choosing instead of `stdout`.